# Valores de Longitud y Latitud en 0 cuando llegan a la acción del controlador

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

solicito de su amable apoyo en este código. Requiero obtener la latitud y longitud de una posición en el googlemaps.

Ahora bien, trabajo con Visual Studio 2019 MVC C#, la acción de mi controlador cuando trae el dato de Latitud y Longitud viene en 0. Tengo dos cajas de texto en la vista de la siguiente forma:

```html
                                        <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Georeferencia:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <div class="form-row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
                                                <label for="validationServer03">Latitud</label>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.i_Latitud, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "LATITUD", disabled = "" })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.i_Latitud, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                <label id="Lat"></label>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
                                                <label for="validationServer03">Longitud</label>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.i_Longitud, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "LATITUD", disabled = "" })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.i_Longitud, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

En mi controlador recibo el modelo con varios campos que traen su información respectiva a excepción de los campos de Latitud y Longitud.

Este es el script de googlemapas para visualizar el mapa y ubicar el arrastre del usuario, lo cual me funciona sin problema:

```html
<script>
        var vMarker
        var map
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
            zoom: 14,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(21.994574, -99.014174),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        vMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(21.994574, -99.014174),
            draggable: true
        });
        latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

        google.maps.event.addListener(vMarker, 'dragend', function (evt) {
            $("#i_Latitud").val(evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(6));
            $("#i_Longitud").val(evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(6));
            map.panTo(evt.latLng);
        });


        map.setCenter(vMarker.position);
        vMarker.setMap(map);
</script>
```

Aquí parte del código de controlador:

```
        public ActionResult GuardarSolicitud(SolicitudesModel solicitudMdl, HttpPostedFileBase pdf_cotizaciondapa, HttpPostedFileBase pdf_cotizacioncfe, HttpPostedFileBase img_evidencia1, HttpPostedFileBase img_evidencia2)
    {
                        Obj.c_latitud = solicitudMdl.i_Latitud.ToString();
                    Obj.c_longitud = solicitudMdl.i_Longitud.ToString();
```

}

Los demás campos vienen con datos y se guarda en la BD de SQL Server sin problema, pero latitud y longitud llegan a la acción del controlador en 0 respectivamente.

Como rescatar esos valores en mis campos del modelo para a la hora de asignarlos a la BD incluyan los valores de Latitud y Longitud.

Agradezco su tiempo, estamos al pendiente.

Answer (score 1):

Amigos mi problema era que tengo un DISABLED en el control, si hubiese puesto un READONLY de igual forma hubiese presentado el fallo, **ya quedo de lado del servidor el valor no se puede recuperar.**

Para quien presente este detallito ahí esta la solución

Hasta luego, gracias a los amigos del FB Ernesto y David que me señalaron el problema en el código.

Comment: Dato importante: los controles que están disabled nunca se mandan al server.